# How do I write messages to the output log on AWS Glue?

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

AWS Glue jobs log output and errors to two different CloudWatch logs, `/aws-glue/jobs/error` and `/aws-glue/jobs/output` by default. When I include `print()` statements in my scripts for debugging, they get written to the error log (`/aws-glue/jobs/error`).

I have tried using:

```
log4jLogger = sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.log4j 
log = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger(__name__) 
log.warn("Hello World!")
```

but "Hello World!" doesn't show up in either of the logs for the test job I ran.

Does anyone know how to go about writing debug log statements to the output log (`/aws-glue/jobs/output`)?

TIA!

EDIT:

It turns out the above actually does work. What was happening was that I was running the job in the AWS Glue Script editor window which captures Command-F key combinations and only searches in the current script. So when I tried to search within the page for the logging output it seemed as if it hadn't been logged.

NOTE: I did discover through testing the first responder's suggestion that AWS Glue scripts don't seem to output any log message with a level less than WARN!

Comment: Do you need to import anything to use `log4jLogger`?Somehow adding these three lines to my script, my job hangs there. The status shows `running` but no log is generated

Comment: This does not work for me in the Glue Job. I am outputting WARN level logs and can not see the min Cloud Watch. Is there anything else you needed to get it working? Thanks

Comment: @padr I had the same problem. When you view the logs, you need to search for the log text in the **filter event** search box. log some nonsense text that will not appear in any other log records to test this.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try to use built-in python logger from `logging` module, by default it writes messages to standard output stream.

```
import logging

MSG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s: %(message)s'
DATETIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
logging.basicConfig(format=MSG_FORMAT, datefmt=DATETIME_FORMAT)
logger = logging.getLogger(<logger-name-here>)

logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

...

logger.info("Test log message")
```

Comment: Turns out the way I was originally trying to log works too. I also discovered that AWS Glue pyspark scripts won't output anything less than a WARN level (see edits above). I'll accept your answer since it works too. Thanks!

Comment: What "<logger-name-here>" i write to do the cloudwatch see my log?

Comment: Any meaningful string you want, for ex. application name. This value will be used in place of `%(name)s` in a log message.

Comment: Is it possible to write only the custom messages to s3?

Comment: Hi I have small question,
logging.basicConfig(filename='s3://<bucketname>/spark.logs',level=logging.INFO)
Can i store log inso into s3 bucket 
I tired by above config, it didnt work @AlexeyBakulin

Comment: What if I want to print out an intermediate data value such as the input data so that I can debug? I used `logger.info(input_data)` seems not working..

Answer (score 40):

I know the article is not new but maybe it could be helpful for someone:
For me logging in glue works with the following lines of code:

```
# create glue context
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
# set custom logging on
logger = glueContext.get_logger()
...
#write into the log file with:
logger.info("s3_key:" + your_value)
```

Comment: what is this s3 key means here? @Lars, is it possible to write the error messages to a file in s3?

Comment: Official documentation on the subject https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuous-logging-enable.html

Comment: Couple of things to note: 1. Glue logger does not take msg format strings, instead it expects full strings (so you have to handle the arguments). 2. Glue logger doesn't seem to be able to be broadcasted out to workers, so if you're trying to log from UDFs you'll need to use the Python logger.

Comment: What if I want to print out an intermediate data value such as the input data so that I can debug? I used `logger.info(input_data)` seems not working..

Comment: @anidev711 the s3 key here is just an example of the content of a log message. You pass whatever you want in the contents of your logs to `logger.info()`

Answer (score 10):

I noticed the above answers are written in python. For Scala you could do the following

```scala
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.log.GlueLogger

object GlueApp {
  def main(sysArgs: Array[String]) {
    val logger = new GlueLogger
    logger.info("info message")
    logger.warn("warn message")
    logger.error("error message")
  }
}
```

You can find both Python and Scala solution from official doc [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuous-logging-enable.html#monitor-continuous-logging-script)

Answer (score 6):

Just in case this helps. This works to change the log level.

```
sc = SparkContext()
sc.setLogLevel('DEBUG')
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
logger = glueContext.get_logger()
logger.info('Hello Glue')
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for INFO level in a Glue Python job:

```
import sys

root = logging.getLogger()
root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
root.addHandler(handler)
root.info("check")
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63361324/6451542)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I resolved it by added
`logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))`

Before there was no prints at all, even ERROR level

The idea was taken from here
https://medium.com/tieto-developers/how-to-do-application-logging-in-aws-745114ac6eb7

> Another option would be to log to stdout and glue AWS logging to stdout (using stdout is actually one of the best practices in cloud logging).

Update: it works only for setLevel("WARNING") and when prints ERROR or WARING. I didn't find how to manage it for the INFO level :(

Comment: Did you check in the error log? That's where my stderr log events end up

Comment: ...same for my stdout log events using a logging.basicConfig

Comment: my prints are not in the stderr

Answer (score 0):

If you're just debugging, `print()` (Python) or `println()` (Scala) works just fine.

Comment: `print()` works, kind of. But all `print()` statements land in a single line in the Glue log which is not ideal.