# Python logging.getLogger not working in AWS Glue python shell job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, logging, aws-glue

I am trying to set up a logger for my AWS Glue job using Python's `logging` module. I have a Glue job with the type as "Python Shell" using Python version 3.

Logging works fine if I instantiate the logger without any `name`, but if I give my logger a `name`, it no longer works, and I get an error which says: `Log stream not found`.

I have the following code in an example Glue job:

```
import sys
import logging

# Version 1 - this works fine
logger = logging.getLogger()
log_format = "[%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s"

# Version 2 - this fails
logger = logging.getLogger(name = "foobar")
log_format = "[%(name)s] %(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s"

date_format = "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"
log_stream = sys.stdout
if logger.handlers:
  for handler in logger.handlers:
    logger.removeHandler(handler)
logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO, format = log_format, stream =
    log_stream, datefmt = date_format)
logger.info("This is a test.")
```

Note that I'm removing the handlers based on [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=288743) post.

If I instantiate the logger using Version 1 of the code, it runs successfully and I am able to view the logs, as well as query them in `CloudWatch`.

If I run Version 2, giving the logger a name, the Glue job still succeeds. However, if I try to view the logs, I get the following error message:

```
Log stream not found
The log stream jr_f137743545d3d242618ac95d859b9146fd15d15a0aadce64d8f3ba991ffed012 could not be found. Check if it was correctly created and retry.
```

And I am also not able to query these logs in `CloudWatch`.

I have tried running this code locally using python version `3.6.0`, and both versions work. Additionally, both versions of this logging code work inside of a Lambda funcvtion. They only fail in Glue.

Answer (score 11):

This code worked for me:

```
import logging
import sys

root = logging.getLogger()
root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
root.addHandler(handler)
root.info("check")
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue but fixed it with a combination of correct roles and looking in the right place in Cloudwatch. Make sure you're using the GlueServiceRole. Both Steve and your logging code is fine but the place that you are taken in Cloudwatch when you click on the "logs" button in Glue isn't the correct logging folder.

Go back into log groups then go into  /aws-glue/python-jobs/error and that is the where the logger write to, while the stdout writes to the folder /aws-glue/python-jobs/output. It's not a very intuitive setup writing the logs to the error logs folder but hey ho, I'm sure there is a way of configuring it to get it to write where expected.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to name the log stream by using the following (replace "logger-name-here" with your desired log stream name):

```
import logging

MSG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s: %(message)s'
DATETIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
logging.basicConfig(format=MSG_FORMAT, datefmt=DATETIME_FORMAT)
logger = logging.getLogger(<logger-name-here>)

logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.info("Test log message")
```

Comment: Hi Greg -- I tried running this code and I'm still getting the same error message that the log stream cannot be not found. Are you able to run this in a Glue python shell job? If so, maybe something is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Actually, if I do this, I can find this log by querying in the Insights page in CloudWatch in the `/aws-glue/python-jobs/error` log group. However, I still get the log stream not found error if I try to view the logs directly in the Glue page, by clicking on the link to the logs in the glue history section. I'd ideally like the log stream to be in the output group, not the error group. Do you know what is going wrong here?